# com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: unconfigured table schema_keyspaces}

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I'm new in Cassandra and can't establish connection. I think I don't have the right version and that's why I'm having this error message. Can someone tell me what version should I use. I'm currently using:

[Screenshot error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqFrV.png)

Cassandra Version: cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.11.10 | CQL spec 3.4.4 | Native protocol v4

Tomcat Version: 9.0.50

JRE Version: jre1.8.0_181

Answer (score 1):

`InvalidQueryException` is typically returned when running a query with a valid CQL syntax but the query itself is invalid.

But in your case where it's reporting an issue with `schema_keyspaces`, it is usually caused by using an older version of the Java driver connecting to a late-release Cassandra version.

If you're building a new app, we recommend that you use the latest version in the Java driver 4.x series. At the time of writing, [the latest release is 4.13](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver/releases).

As a side note if you're just learning how to build apps for Cassandra, I recommend using [Astra DB](https://dtsx.io/2XM1INf). You can launch a Cassandra cluster in just a few clicks and there's a free tier with no credit card required.

Astra DB also has [Stargate.io](https://dtsx.io/2XHbiRo) already bundled in and pre-configured so you can connect to Cassandra using REST API, GraphQL API and JSON/Doc API. If you're interested, we have free hands-on interactive tutorials on Cassandra, Stargate and how to build apps at [datastax.com/dev](https://dtsx.io/3ggnQWa). Cheers!

Comment: Hey, so I could go over your response but still having some troubles with my dependencies. I'm not sure which one is incorrect. Could you me tell what version should I use if I'm using the java-driver-core 4.13.0. My dependencies are:
Java-driver-core           version 4.13.0
java-driver-query-builder    version 4.13.0
java-driver-mapper-runtime version 4.13.0
guava version 14.0.1
log4j-over-slf4j versiona1.7.13
metrics-core version3.0.2
netty-all 4.0.28.Final
slf4j-api version1.7.13
slf4j-nop version 1.7.21

Comment: I've responded to your question here -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68856818/. Cheers!