# What dependencies should I use for Cassandra Java driver 4.13?

Tags: cassandra, cql, cassandra-3.0, cassandra-2.0

so I'm having some trouble when I connect to Cassandra(Version:3.11.10).

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.AbstractMethodError:
```

Could someone tell me what dependencies should I use for it if I'm using java-driver-core 4.13.0. My currently dependencies are:

Java-driver-core version 4.13.0
Java-driver-query-builder version 4.13.0
Java-driver-mapper-runtime version 4.13.0
Guava version 14.0.1
log4j-over-slf4j versiona 1.7.13
metrics-core version 3.0.2
netty-all 4.0.28.Final
slf4j-api version 1.7.13
slf4j-nop version 1.7.21

And also could you share your example of your class connection. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a sample `pom.xml` from the [Java driver manual](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.13/manual/core/integration/):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.example.yourcompany</groupId>
  <artifactId>yourapp</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.datastax.oss</groupId>
      <artifactId>java-driver-core</artifactId>
      <version>${driver.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
      <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

In case you weren't aware, we have a free [hands-on tutorial here](https://dtsx.io/3gkfo8x) that will show you how to do CRUD operations with the Java driver. There are lots of other free interactive tutorials at [datastax.com/dev](https://dtsx.io/3ggnQWa) that I think you'll find useful.

As a side note, as a developer you might be interested in [Stargate.io](https://dtsx.io/2XHbiRo) -- a data platform that lets you connect to Cassandra using REST, GraphQL and JSON/Doc APIs. For example, creating a new record is as easy as sending a `POST` request to `/api/rest/v2/keyspaces/db_name/table_name/`. You can easily do CRUD operations with API calls in your app. It is open-source so it's free to use.

You can try it free (no credit card required) -- [Astra DB](https://dtsx.io/2XM1INf) comes with Stargate bundled in so it's pre-configured and ready to use. Launch a free Cassandra cluster in just [a few clicks here](https://dtsx.io/2XM1INf) to play with Stargate. Cheers!

Comment: I've tried with those dependencies and I have this error 

"org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Missing implementation of resolved method 'abstract io.netty.util.concurrent.EventExecutor newChild(java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory, java.lang.Object[])' of abstract class io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup."

Comment: Finally, it has worked!! I only used the dependencies that you sent me and it worked smooth. I think my problem was because I was using so many dependencies like: Java-driver-query-builder, Java-driver-mapper-runtime version and many more when I should have used only the Java-Driver-Core one. Hope this helps someone. 2 weeks of work.